# Cannot insert to collection from NPM using Meteor 1.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor, npm

I am using the imap-simple NPM package to check emails, and I am having trouble getting the insert to work properly.

I have already read through this page: https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#async-callbacks - and I have tried the suggestions but none of them are working!

I've also simplified the code a bit just to try to get it working, but still have no luck.

The problem should be very easy to reproduce - meteor npm install imap-simple, throw the above code on the server, add some email credentials, and call the method.

Here is my code:

```
var imaps = require('imap-simple');
var config = {
    imap: {
        user: '<removed>',
        password: '<removed>',
        host: 'imap.gmail.com',
        port: 993,
        tls: true,
        authTimeout: 3000
    }
};

Meteor.methods({

    api_connectEmail: function () {
        console.log('Received call to connect email');

        imaps.connect(config).then(function (connection) {

            return connection.openBox('INBOX').then(function () {
                var searchCriteria = [
                    'UNSEEN'
                ];

                var fetchOptions = {
                    bodies: ['HEADER', 'TEXT'],
                    markSeen: true
                };

                return connection.search(searchCriteria, fetchOptions).then(function (results) {
                    results.map(function (res) {

                        var subject = res.parts.filter(function (part) {return part.which === 'HEADER';})[0].body.subject[0];
                        console.log("Subject: " + subject);

                        // insert
                        var attributes = {
                            subject: subject
                        };
                        console.log("Attempting to insert to collection...");
                        var newData = TempEmailCollection.insert(attributes);
                        console.log("New Database Entry ID: " + newData);

                    });
                });
            });
        })
    }
});
```

The console.log with the subject is working. The insert is not working. No error, no console.log post insert, nothing.

I've tried both strategies recommended in the guide, neither work.

Comment: what is TempEmailCollection?

Comment: @Darren a Mongo collection made specifically to contain the mail information. Normally everywhere in Meteor, .insert works on collections. But not on NPM modules. And the traditionally way of working around is not working for me.

Comment: You need to show its code; this entire question appears to be related to that, and not the email (which you say is working)

Comment: @Darren I think you misunderstand. In Meteor, collections do not have "code". It takes a single line to create a collection - TempEmailCollection = new Mongo.Collection('temp_email');

Everywhere in a Meteor project, you can manipulate collections, except for NPM which runs off a different fiber it seems.

Comment: More specifically, the NPM module is working correctly. But the scope is wrong - NPM is not able to use Meteor's mongo collection features.

The link I provided explains how to work around this, but the work around did not help in this situation, probably due to how the search feature works.

Comment: No misunderstanding - just didn't know what TempEmailCollection as you have nothing else in your code showing its definition

Comment: Ah okay well, hope it clears things up, I simplified it a bit before asking for help and now it's just an empty mongo collection w/ no set schema. Inserting works everywhere else in the project, except in the NPM features linked above. 

I even tried making it through a separate function on the server. I can call the function from anywhere in project, it works fine. Except if I call the function from this code, it still doesn't work. No error reports either... but everything past the "insert" line does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling a Meteor function inside asynchronously called Promise handlers.
However, all Meteor functions that are called on the server have to run in a fiber.
Meteor actually throws an error in this case but you are ignoring it because you haven't specified `catch` functions for the Promises.

Consider the following simplified example (it just connects to the server and tries to insert a new document):

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import imaps from 'imap-simple';

const Storage = new Mongo.Collection('storage');

const config = {
  imap: {
    …
  }
};

Meteor.methods({
  connect() {
    console.log('Method called');

    imaps.connect(config).then(function(connection) {
      console.log('Connected');

      Storage.insert({
        value: 'success'
      });

      console.log('Document inserted');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
});
```

The following message will arrive in the `catch` function:

`[Error: Meteor code must always run within a Fiber. Try wrapping callbacks that you pass to non-Meteor libraries with Meteor.bindEnvironment.]`

You could do something like this to wrap the `insert` call:

```
Meteor.methods({
  connect() {
    console.log('Method called');

    const insert = Meteor.bindEnvironment(function() {
      Storage.insert({
        value: 'success'
      });
    });

    imaps.connect(config).then(function(connection) {
      console.log('Connected');
      insert();
      console.log('Document inserted');
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  }
});
```

Then the document will be inserted as expected.